# Add listener to all Elements with a given class

Tags: extjs

I'm normally a jQuery developer and have to work on an extJs Project.
It's the ExtCore v. 3.1.0 without any extensions (and an update isn't possible yet)

So now my problem...
I need something similar to this jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on('focusin', 'input[type="text"]', function(event){
  $(this).empty();
});
```

But I can't find anything to add Eventlistneres to multiple elements.
Is that possible with just the extCore?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`addListener`](http://docs.sencha.com/core/#Ext.Element-methods) with delegate (or use `on` which is a shorthand for `addListener`):

> Appends an event handler to this element. The shorthand version on is
>   equivalent.

The delegate is a simple selector to filter the target or look for a descendant of the target.

For example:

```
var el = Ext.getBody();
el.on('click', function (event, elem) {
   .
   .
   .
},
this, {
    delegate: 'input[type="text"]'
});
```

Comment: Thanks that for I was looking for a long long time ;-)